# How to extract arbitrary number of data points from data tip cursor in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, pause

I am trying to display a sequence of figures (in the example code below, 2 figures) such that I will go through each figure one by one and click on some points and output the (x,y) position of the points from the cursor. Following some online help, I use the `pause` function, I click on one point, press a key which outputs the (x,y) data to the Matlab terminal using `datacursormode` and `getCursorInfo` functions and then click on the next point. I don't know how many points I am going to select in each figure but let's say it is going to be less than 10. Therefore, I am using a `for` loop (`for rc1=1:10`) with a pause statement in it. The problem is I don't know how to exit this loop when I am finished with a fewer number of points (lets say at `rc1=5`) and move to the next figure. How do I do this ? If the code could take some indication that I have finished selecting points from a current figure and let me break out of the `rc1=1:10` loop (for example, some kind of `if (condition) continue` statement after `if isfield ... end` should work).

```
clc
clearvars
close all

for rc2=1:2
    
    figure;
    
    x = linspace(0,10,150);
    y = cos(5*x);
    fig = gcf;
    plot(x,y)
    % Enable data cursor mode
    datacursormode on
    dcm_obj = datacursormode(fig);
    % Set update function
    set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',@myupdatefcn)
    % Wait while the user to click
    disp('Click line to display a data tip, then press "Return"');
    
    for rc1=1:10
        pause
        % Export cursor to workspace
        info_struct = getCursorInfo(dcm_obj);
        if isfield(info_struct, 'Position')
            fprintf('%.2f %.2f \n',info_struct.Position);
        end
        
     end
    
end

function output_txt = myupdatefcn(~,event_obj)
% ~            Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Object containing event data structure
% output_txt   Data cursor text
pos = get(event_obj, 'Position');
output_txt = {['x: ' num2str(pos(1))], ['y: ' num2str(pos(2))]};
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. Adding a `try, catch, break, end` sequence in the inner loop and putting the `pause, getCursorInfo, isfield` segment within the `try` section made it work. Now I select few points, simply close the current figure, press a key and move on to the next figure. This works.

```
clc
clearvars
close all

for rc2=1:2
    
    figure;
    
    x = linspace(0,10,150);
    y = cos(5*x);
    fig = gcf;
    plot(x,y)
    % Enable data cursor mode
    datacursormode on
    dcm_obj = datacursormode(fig);
    % Set update function
    set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',@myupdatefcn)
    % Wait while the user to click
    disp('Click line to display a data tip, then press "Return"');
    
    for rc1=1:10
        % Export cursor to workspace
        try
            pause
            info_struct = getCursorInfo(dcm_obj);
            if isfield(info_struct, 'Position')
                fprintf('%.2f %.2f \n',info_struct.Position);
            end
        catch
            break;
        end
     end
    
end

function output_txt = myupdatefcn(~,event_obj)
% ~            Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Object containing event data structure
% output_txt   Data cursor text
pos = get(event_obj, 'Position');
output_txt = {['x: ' num2str(pos(1))], ['y: ' num2str(pos(2))]};
end
```